# Selected Index Change and button click in same row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

So I am making a site. I have table and in table there is `selectedindexchange` and under the table there is button.

Now i have problem when i click on `Odaberi`(selec.index.chang.) and then on button `Pošalji predbiljezbu` it doesn't save those data in same row in sql.

It saves in 2 rows, in first row it saves `IdSeminar` and in second one `Ime`, `Prezime` and `Adresa` but i want that all in one single row

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with code, instead of pictures of code and pictures of rendered html. We need your markup instead of the page.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question will be easier to answer if you copy and paste the code your having difficulty with into your question. For more help how to ask a question see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve